# Angular: dismiss modal when browser back button pressed and cancel navigation

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I'm trying to dismiss a full-window modal when the browser back button is pressed with this code:

```
class MyModalComponent {
  constructor(private _location: LocationStrategy) { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this._location.pushState(this.url, this.title, this.url, '');
  }

  @HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
  public onPopState(event: PopStateEvent) {
      this.modal.dismiss();
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.cancelBubble = true;
  }
}
```

When the back button is pressed, `onPopState` is invoked and the modal is dismissed, but also Angular Router detects the URL change and starts navigating to the previous state. Is there any way to cancel the navigation or prevent Angular Router listening to URL changes when a modal is open?

Comment: You certainly can prevent route change conditionally, what you want to use is `canDeactivate`. You can find a good example [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#candeactivate-handling-unsaved-changes)

Comment: This modals are shown almost everywhere, `canDeactive` is not an option. Is there any kind of global `canDeactive`?
Even if using `canDeactive` solves the issue, it would mean mixing the modal logic with other components logic that just use those modals.

Comment: `canDeactive` is the best approach, in combination with a notification service which id recommend implementing. That will handle all the logic regarding modals, toasts, loading, etc.

Comment: I'm using and notification service, but the components created by that service are created "outside" the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and thus `canDeactive` is not invoked for them

Answer (score 1):

One dirty solution could be using `onSameUrlNavigation` router property set to `'ignore'` and pushing the current URL into the navigation history to prevent back button invoking a router navigation:

```
class MyModalComponent {
  private _prevOnSameUrlNavigation; 

  constructor(private _location: LocationStrategy, private _router: Router) {

  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this._prevOnSameUrlNavigation = this._router.onSameUrlNavigation;
    this._router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'ignore';
    this._location.pushState("Modal state", "Modal title", this._router.url, '');
  }

  @HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
  public onPopState(event: PopStateEvent) {
      this.modal.dismiss();
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.cancelBubble = true;
  }

  public ngOnDestroy() {
      this._router.onSameUrlNavigation = this._prevOnSameUrlNavigation;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ive got workaround. You need to manually remove modal parts like so...

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from "@angular/router";

import { map } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  loading: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private _loading: LoadingService,
    private router: Router
  ){
    router.events.subscribe((val) => {
        if(val instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          if(document.body.classList[0] == 'modal-open')  {
            document.body.classList.remove("modal-open");
            const over = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-backdrop')[0]
            if(over){
              over.parentNode!.removeChild(over);
            }
          }
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: This is indeed a workaround, and depends on the specific class-names etc. Best to handle this another way.